# Access Network Information through an Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, wifimanager

I have an android emulator. I would like to develop an application to measure the signal strength (RSSI) from the Acess Point. 
I would like to poll the signal strength and update the metric about the signal strength.

I am using **WifiManager**. But as I run the application, I get the following output,

```
WIFI Status:SSID<none>,BSSID:<none>,MAC:<none>..
```

Is it possible to develop such an application.

Regards
Chandra

Comment: How do you expect the emulator to see wifi signals?

Comment: Is there anyway I could use the WIFI related API's with a Android emulator.